# Querying snowflake metadata using spark connector

Tags: apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I want to run 'SHOW TABLES' statement through the spark-snowflake connector, I am running the spark on a Databricks platform and getting "Object 'SHOW' does not exist or not authorized" error.

```
df = spark.read \
  .format("snowflake") \
  .options(**options) \
  .option("query",  "show tables") \
  .load()

df.show()
```

Sample query like "SELECT 1" is working as expected.
I know that I am able to install the native python-snowflake driver but I want to avoid this solution if possible because I already opened the session using spark.

There is also a way using "Utils.runQuery" function but I understood that is relevant only for DDL statement (It doesn't return the actual results).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using DataFrames, the Snowflake connector supports SELECT queries only.
This is documented on our [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#moving-data-from-snowflake-to-spark).

Comment: Understood, so unfortunately my only solution is to install the python-snowflake connector in addition.
Thanks